# Pie Menu for Pivot Point

Tags: python, scripting, pie-menu

I want to build a custom piemenu wich contains the following: Proportianal Editing and Changing the Pivot point.

There are already two pie menus, which does those options, but I have only one button for that.

So I want an pie menu which contains following commands:

```
#bpy.context.space_data.pivot_point = 'CURSOR'
#bpy.context.space_data.pivot_point = 'INDIVIDUAL_ORIGINS'
#bpy.context.space_data.pivot_point = 'MEDIAN_POINT'
#bpy.context.space_data.pivot_point = 'ACTIVE_ELEMENT'
```

and also some commands for proportional editing, which allready working.

but I don't know how to ipmlement these operators, because at all others, there is something infront of the equal sign.